# expected table, got number when replacing strings with gsub

Tags: lua, neovim

I have an `kaymaps.lua` file where I have configured all my keymaps in nvim.

I'm adding this piece of code:

```lua
local keymap = vim.keymap -- keymaps

-- go to tab [1-9]
for i = 1, 9, 1 do
  keymap.set("n", string.gsub("<leader>@", "@", i), string.gsub("<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer @<CR>", "@", i))
end
```

In order to do:

```lua
keymap.set("n", "<leader>1", "<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer 1<CR>")
.
.
.
keymap.set("n", "<leader>9", "<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer 9<CR>")
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```bash
Error detected while processing /Users/diego/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: vim/keymap.lua:0: opts: expected table, got number
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        vim/shared.lua: in function 'validate'
        vim/keymap.lua: in function 'set'
        /Users/diego/.config/nvim/lua/diegoulloao/core/keymaps.lua:26: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /Users/diego/.config/nvim/lua/diegoulloao/bootstrap.lua:6: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /Users/diego/.config/nvim/init.lua:2: in main chunk
```

If you try this piece of code in https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

```lua
for i = 1, 9, 1
do
    print(string.gsub("<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer @<CR>", "@", i))
end
```

You get as output:

```bash
<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer 1<CR> 1
<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer 2<CR> 1
<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer 3<CR> 1
<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer 4<CR> 1
<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer 5<CR> 1
<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer 6<CR> 1
<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer 7<CR> 1
<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer 8<CR> 1
<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer 9<CR> 1
```

I can see a number `1` at the end of each line, so I was wondering if that's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string.gsub` returns multiple values. When a function that returns multiple values is the last argument to another function, all of the values get passed. This means you're really running `keymap.set("n", "<leader>1", "<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer 1<CR>", 1)`. To suppress that behavior, wrap the whole inner function call in parentheses, like this:

```
keymap.set("n", string.gsub("<leader>@", "@", i), (string.gsub("<cmd>BufferLineGoToBuffer @<CR>", "@", i)))
```

Comment: That works! I had to wrap both `gsub`. Thank you!!